# How to fix error java.util.InputMismatchException?

Tags: java

I want to know how to change the input with no string. When I take the input in the form of characters or strings, it is throwing error. Can anyone suggest me how to fix it?

Let's take an example when I take input "Y" it is throwing error  java.util.InputMismatchException

Here is the code:

```
        double minBelanja,diskon,potonganHarga,totalBelanja;
        int jumlahItem;
        boolean persyaratan,error;

        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        diskon = 0.0;

        do {
        System.out.print("Masukan Total Belanja = ");
        minBelanja = userInput.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Masukan Jumlah Item Belanja = ");
        jumlahItem = userInput.nextInt();

        persyaratan = (minBelanja > 0 && jumlahItem > 0);

        if (persyaratan==false) {
            System.out.print("\nMaaf Input Anda Salah \n");
            }
        } while (persyaratan!=true);

        if(jumlahItem >= 15 && minBelanja >= 500000)
            diskon = 0.2;
        else if (jumlahItem >=5 && minBelanja >= 250000)
            diskon = 0.1;
        else if (jumlahItem >=1 && minBelanja >= 100000)
            diskon = 0.05;
        else
            System.out.println("\nMaaf anda tidak mendapat diskon");

        potonganHarga = minBelanja*diskon;
        totalBelanja = minBelanja - potonganHarga;

        if(diskon==0)
            System.out.printf("Total Belanja Anda = %.2f",totalBelanja);
        else {
            System.out.printf("%nSelamat anda Mendapat Diskon = %.2f %n",potonganHarga);
            System.out.printf("Total Belanja Anda Sekaran = %.2f %n",totalBelanja);
        }
        userInput.close();
```

Comment: Please clarify what you're trying to accomplish and remove any non-essential code from code sample. Where exactly does exception occur? It seems like you're expecting user input in the form of double or int. What is it you want to happen if non-numeric input is provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Fauzan, you have to keep the below code inside try block and handle the exception in catch block.

Replace this:

```
do {
    System.out.print("Masukan Total Belanja = ");
    minBelanja = userInput.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Masukan Jumlah Item Belanja = ");
    jumlahItem = userInput.nextInt();

    persyaratan = (minBelanja > 0 && jumlahItem > 0);

    if (persyaratan==false) {
        System.out.print("\nMaaf Input Anda Salah \n");
        }
    } while (persyaratan!=true);
```

with this code:

```
try {
   do {
    System.out.print("Masukan Total Belanja = ");
    minBelanja = userInput.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Masukan Jumlah Item Belanja = ");
    jumlahItem = userInput.nextInt();

    persyaratan = (minBelanja > 0 && jumlahItem > 0);

    if (persyaratan==false) {
        System.out.print("\nMaaf Input Anda Salah \n");
        }
    } while (persyaratan!=true);
} catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
     System.out.println("You did not enter a number");
}
```

And always keep the risky codes in try block and handle them. Here in your case you didn't keep that code inside try block which causes error. So if you keep in try block then if any error comes then catch block will be executed and there you can show some message to the user as above.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you want to use a pattern like

```
double input = -1;
while (input == -1) {
  try {
    input = userInput.nextDouble();
  }
  catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
    System.out.println("You did not enter a number. Please try again");
  }
}
```